# Mysql: On some duplicate column insert on all duplicate update

Tags: mysql

So I am trying to make a views counter and my table looks like this.

```
post_id  |  view_count  |  view_ip
----------------------------------
20       |           1  |  some ip
21       |           1  |  some ip
```

At this point I'm so lost that I know it's wrong to make it like that but I have no idea how to do it.

So at the moment I'm calling the views with count(post_id) and it gives me 1 but when I open the site with my phone (not on wifi) I expect to have a second row with post_id = 20 but the duplicate activates and I am not making the new insert...

Here is my query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `views`
SET view_count=1, post_id = '.$article['post_id'].', view_ip = "'.$ip.'"
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE view_count=view_count;
```

Somewhere in stack there was an answer how to skip update and that was recommended but I'm not sure if this is ok...

P.S.:
   The idea is to have one view per ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantically you're trying to express "Insert a new view for this post, but if it already have a view, add one".

This can be done with:

```
INSERT INTO `views` (post_id, view_count, view_ip)
VALUES (?, 1, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE view_count = view_count + 1;
```

You'll need a uniq index on `(post_id, view_ip)` for the `DUPLICATE KEY` to happen.

Oh and please, please refrain to concatenate strings to forge SQL queries, this is the way to [SQL Injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Please use prepared statements, prepared statements offers really clean (visually and technically) way to do put values in a statement, and it does it very safely server-side.

When I say it's "visually clean" I mean I prefer:

```
view_ip = ?
```

over:

```
view_ip = "'.$ip.'"
```

Plus the second one is highly prone to SQL injections.

(The `?` placeholder may vary from a system to another).

Comment: It' didn't work. Btw $ip has a check for SQL injections and checks if it's X_FORWARDED_FOR before the query.

The problem now is that it writes in the same row despite the IP. The idea is that one IP has one view on an article.

Comment: You're probably missing the uniq index. Please show a `show create table` of your table. And please do not think you're able to check for SQL injections, nobody is, just use prepared statements, don't try to do it yourself. (of maybe removing every character is a good prevention against injections, so one is able to pre-filter for SQL injections, don't take me literally).

Comment: I have decided to use another method. I have access only to phpmyadmin and I was not sure if the unique was set properly. Thank you anyway!